# How format a TimeSpan to short date using DisplayFormat DataFormatString data-annotation?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, data-annotations, poco

How use attribute data-annotation in a POCO class to format a `TimeSpan` to short time. I tried

```
[DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:t}")]
public TimeSpan MyTime { get; set; }
```

without success

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fonud that the usual string format for `DateTime` **are not the same for** `TimeSpan`.

In this case the short time formatting shoud be done manually like this:

```
[DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:hh\\:mm}")]
public TimeSpan MyTime { get; set; }
```